# Cannot draw correct chart in Google sheets (Google script)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to create chart, but I got an issue.

```
var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataSheet_3 = ss.getSheets()[3]; 
var chart = dataSheet.newChart();
chart.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA);
chart.addRange(currentSheet.getRange("E22:E41")); 
chart.addRange(currentSheet.getRange("F22:F41")); 
chart.setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0);
currentSheet.insertChart(chart.build());
```

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6Fj.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding this?

```
chart.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true);
```

#### Script :

```
var chart = dataSheet.newChart();
chart.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA);
chart.addRange(currentSheet.getRange("E22:E41")); 
chart.addRange(currentSheet.getRange("F22:F41")); 
chart.setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0);
chart.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true); // Added
currentSheet.insertChart(chart.build());
```

#### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder

  - I found a sample script before. But I got it by testing some cases because I'm not sure the detail information.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.